# Bad Dates: SQL Server Offers ISDATE(), But Informix Does Not. Is There an Equal Workaround?

Tags: sql-server, date, null, informix

I am dealing with legacy Informix data apparently never validated properly upon input.

This means that a DATE field could contain

- a proper date (12/25/2000),
- a garbage date (02/22/0200),
- NULL, or
- the Lindbergh baby.

The following works nicely in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS [Grand Total Count of Bad-Date Records],
    COUNT(GOOFYDATE) AS [Count of Just NON-NULL Bad-Date Records],
    SUM(IIF(GOOFYDATE IS NULL,1,0)) AS [Count of Just NULL Bad-Date Records]
FROM MyTable
WHERE ISDATE(GOOFYDATE)=0
```

Everything above adds up.

In Informix,

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATE(GOOFYDATE) IS NULL
```

gives me the Grand Total, as before.  However, the following does, too:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM MyTable
WHERE DATE(GOOFYDATE) IS NULL
AND GOOFYDATE IS NULL
```

How may I implement in Informix my ISDATE goal, as accomplished above in SQL Server?

Comment: Presumably the field containing the date is not defined as type `DATE` for you to find 'goofy' dates stored in it?

Comment: If the legacy system designers had done their job properly, there'd be no issue. Either DATE or DATETIME YEAR TO DAY would not allow any invalid dates into the system (but there could be NULL values unless there was a NOT NULL constraint).  Be wary of locale issues with converting strings to dates.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo.  All should be "GOOFYDATE."

Comment: Believe it or not, the Informix field IS defined as "DATE," and it contains thousands of beauties such as: "01/02/0001", "01/06/0200", "12/15/0999", "12/31/1899", "05/03/5001", etc. Contrary to the type definition, those odd values indeed found their way into an Informix DATE field (but I do not know how).

Comment: That completely changes the question! All those values can be interpreted as dates, they just don't fall within a reasonable domain. You could write something much simpler to return 0 if input is null, lower than a reasonable bound or greater than a reasonable upper bound, else 1. The reference to the Lindbergh Baby suggested the data held random text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a stored procedure/function to perform this task, so that it will work exactly like the SQL Server equivalent. Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION informix.isdate(str VARCHAR(50), fmt VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNING SMALLINT;
    DEFINE d DATE;

    ON EXCEPTION IN (-1277,-1267,-1263) -- other errors are possible
        RETURN 0;
    END EXCEPTION;

    LET d = TO_DATE(str, fmt); -- acceptable date if exception not raised
    IF d < MDY(1,1,1850) THEN -- dates prior to this are "logically invalid"
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
    RETURN 1;
END FUNCTION;
```

Which you can use thus:

```
-- Sample data
CREATE TEMP TABLE test1 (str VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ("not a date");
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ("02/25/2016");
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ("02/30/2016");
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ("02/01/0000");

SELECT str, ISDATE(str, "%m/%d/%Y") FROM test1;

str                                                (expression)

not a date                                                    0
02/25/2016                                                    1
02/30/2016                                                    0
02/01/0000                                                    0

4 row(s) retrieved.

SELECT str AS invalid_date
  FROM test1
  WHERE ISDATE(str, "%m/%d/%Y") = 0;

invalid_date

not a date
02/30/2016
02/01/0000

3 row(s) retrieved.
```

Depending on how goofy your dates are, you may find other errors crop up. Just adjust the `ON EXCEPTION` clause accordingly. I've written this function to be as general purpose as possible, but you could code the "accepted" date format into the routine rather than pass it as an argument. (I don't recommend that, though.)

Comment: From what I see, the code decides that the string is not a proper date, if the conversion of the string to date fails or if the resultant date occurs prior to New Year's Day 1850.

The error numbers seem to come out of nowhere.  Other than through trial and error, is there an easy way to divine them?

Comment: Tried the function, as follows:
`SELECT GoofyDate,
    ISDATE(GoofyDate, "%m/%d/%Y"), (GoofyDate IS NULL)
FROM MyTable`
Unfortunately, ISDATE produces 1 (true) for NULL dates.  Looks like all that the function needs is a replacement of the line `IF d < MDY(1,1,1850) THEN RETURN 0;` with `IF (d IS NULL) OR (d < MDY(1,1,1850)) THEN RETURN 0;`.

Comment: NULL might be considered valid for a date field (eg a delete_date or close_date), so personally I would be loath to include that in such a function. You can always write `(ISDATE(...) = 0 OR str IS NULL)`. However if that's what SQL Server does and you're trying to emulate it, then go right ahead.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server's ISDATE produces 0 (false) for NULL items.  That worked fine for my table, where NULL dates never should have occurred.  On the Informix side, I may create an ISDATEORNULL function, per your example, for the instances you describe.  Thanks for the advice.